# How to define a class in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, definition

How to define a class in Python 3.4?

I've tried this one:

```
Class NewClass{
   int i;
}
```

but that does not work. The compiler says "unresolved reference".

I dont understand it. Thank you...

Comment: Why did you think that would work? It is nowhere near Python syntax (2.x or 3.x). Please see the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class statement creates a new class definition. The name of the class immediately follows the keyword class followed by a colon as follows:

```
class ClassName:
  statement-1
  .
  .
  .
  statement-N
```

look here:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html